# mini scripting language on top of php

Tags: php, scripting, programming-languages, embedded

I am looking for a mini scripting language that runs on php, I need to interpret simple formulas (something that a scripting language for a spreadsheet would do). The main thing that I need is Variables and affectation and mathematical operations conditions and if statement.

ex :

if(price1>360)
    result = (price1 * Q) + price1 * Q /17
else ...

Comment: Why not just write PHP then? Adding more language layers just slows things down.

Comment: I need to limit what the user can do, and I want to convert it into a non English language.

Comment: How a framework would help me ?

Comment: @Ayoub You can read about it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework

Comment: @sombe I will not use it to build application, but in part of the application the uses will enter simple mathematical formulas with conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at some of the concepts used in a template system like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) and implement your own. For instance, the [math template](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.math.tpl) allows you to perform operations like this:

```
{* $height=4, $width=5 *}
{math equation="x + y" x=$height y=$width}
```

You can just grab the [math functions from here](http://code.google.com/p/pear-smarty/source/browse/tags/Smarty/2.6.20/plugins/function.math.php?r=11), if you want a general guideline of how to create them.  There is still a risk of issues since this uses `eval()` to do the computations.

In addition, [here is a class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4078-PHP-Evaluate-reverse-polish-notation-expressions.html) to evaluate RPN (Reverse Polish Notation) to support the operators: `+, - , *, /, IF, THEN, SWAP, DUP, =, <>, >, <. >=` and `<=` .

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could also write these little scripts in PHP and execute them using [eval](http://www.php.net/eval). But, since this is like opening Pandora's box, you should really know you can trust the code that is passed, before considering this as a viable option (ie. it's dangerous, really, especially if these formulas are entered by users - I would *never* use them when users provide the code to be executed).

Another option (probably safer) would be to use some form of javascript interpreter to execute the snippets. There are 2 PHP projects I know of that could be helpful (even though they seem to be in hibernation) : [j4p5](http://j4p5.sourceforge.net/) and [phpjs](http://phpjs.berlios.de/). If you can install extensions then [PECL with SpiderMonkey](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4704) could be a better option though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an embedded interpreter e.g. Javascript like http://phpjs.berlios.de/ or wrapping command line calls to spider monkey.